# How to pragmatically set/change the color of the Toolbar home icon?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have setup the following `AppBarLayout` + `TabLayout` for the main activity of my Android app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        ...>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            ... />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    ...
```

Basically it looks like this:

[image]

**The question is:** How can I **pragmatically** change the color of the **home icon** (the hamburger icon in the picture)?

Setting the color within my the XML syltes is no problem:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ff00ff00</item>
    ...
</style>
```

But how can I change this pragmatically at runtime? There seems to be no setter for textColorSecondary...

Comment: Are you setting that icon yourself? Or is it coming from an `ActionBarDrawerToggle`? If the former, you could first load the image as a `Drawable`, set that on the `Toolbar`, then control the color with `Drawable`'s `setColorFilter()` or `setTint()` methods. If the latter, there's the `getDrawerArrowDrawable()` method, and you can `setColor()` directly on that.

Comment: Thanks, using `getDrawerArrowDrawable()` solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, I do not believe you can set the style programatically. What you can do, however, is changing the style ( while keeping the same values) but only changing `textColorSecondary` value

Comment: Thanks, but how can I update the Toolbar style programmatically?

Comment: `Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar.getContext().setTheme(R.style.your_theme);`

Comment: Mmh, this does not seem to work. While the effect of `toolbar.setBackgroundColor(...)` and other setters becomes visible immediately setting the theme has no effect